# Reuse the same template for different content types

Tags: templates, plone, grok, dexterity

I'm creating quite a few Dexterity content types (thanks [zopeskel.dexterity](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopeskel.dexterity) devs!!) but even if I need them to be different content types (searches, collections...), some of them will be rendered equally.

So, there's any way to reuse the same template for different content types?

Ok, I made it work but I'm wondering if it's the correct approach:

```
from my.product.parent_type import IParentType, ParentType, TwoColumnsView

... code omitted ...

# Common folder for templates
grok.templatedir('parent_type_templates')

class SameTwoColumnsView(TwoColumnsView):
    grok.context(CustomClass)
    grok.require('zope2.View')

    grok.template("twocolumnsview")
```

Any thought? **How do you reuse templates across content types?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an interface for this:

```
from zope.interface import Interface

class ITwoColumnViewable(Interface):
    """Can be viewed in a 2-column layout"""
```

You then assign this interface to your various content types, and register the view for that interface instead directly for a type:

```
class SameTwoColumnsView(TwoColumnsView):
    grok.context(ITwoColumnViewable)
```